# Need Optimized code for the scenario: Tag contactId in Lead if a contact exist with matching email id as that of lead(Lead is a child to Contact))

Tags: apex, trigger

Need Optimized code for the scenario: Tag contactId in Lead if a contact exist with matching email id as that of the lead (Lead is a child to Contact)):

**My code:**

```
trigger LeadContact on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    List<string> emailList = new list<string>();
    List<lead> leadList=new list<lead>();
    for(Lead l:Trigger.new)
    {
        if(l.email!=null)
        {
            emailList.add(l.email);
        }
   }

   List<contact> conlist =[select id,email from contact where email in: emailList];

    for(lead l:Trigger.new)
    {
        for(contact c:conlist)
        {
            if(l.email==c.email)
            {
                l.Contact__c=c.id;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For this type of scenario, you need to think of the [Map class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm).

You'll be able to link each lead `Email` to its instance.

Here's the code for your requirement:

```
trigger LeadContact on Lead (before insert, before update) {

    Map<String, Lead> leadByEmail = new Map<String, Lead>();
    for(Lead l:Trigger.new)
    {
          if(l.email!=null)
         {
           leadByEmail.put(l.email, l);
        }
   }

    for(contact c : [select id,email from contact where email in: leadByEmail.keySet()]){
        leadByEmail.get(c.Email).Contact__c = c.Id;  
    }

  }
```